# SendKeys for Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, sendkeys, xamarin.mac

I am building a Mac app in Xamarin and have a need to send keystrokes (with words and phrases) to other applications. Something like SendKeys in .Net on Windows.

Is there a SendKeys equivalent API for Mac in Xamarin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent` is what you are looking for, it is Quartz-based and thus a low-level `C` API.

Xamarin has a shim-wrapper over it via an `CGEvent` `.ctor`. After you create the event, include any-keyboard modifiers (shift/apple/alt/....), you can `Post` it to a process id of your choosing.

#### Really quick example that sends `stackoverflow` to active process/window.

```
using (var eventSource = new CGEventSource(CGEventSourceStateID.HidSystem))
{
    var eventString = "StackOverflow";
    foreach (var eventChar in eventString)
    {
        //  my most favorite Enum.Parse line ever written 
        var key = (ushort)(NSKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(NSKey), eventChar.ToString().ToUpper());

        using (var keyEvent = new CGEvent(eventSource, key, true))
        {
            CGEvent.Post(keyEvent, CGEventTapLocation.HID);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: To see it in action, place a `Task.Delay` before it, run it and then switch to/activate an editor, maybe Visual Studio for Mac :-) and let it type into the active editor panel.

FYI: You might want to refer to the Xamarin wrapper/source code for `CGEvent.cs`, as their naming is not vary ObjC or Swift friendly in terms of be able from translate Apple docs to `Xamarin.Mac` code.

Re: [xamarin-macios/src/CoreGraphics/CGEvent.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/c0202e0e2be22bc1e9ff08e26473b9ae102842d7/src/CoreGraphics/CGEvent.cs)