# Sending keystroke to active application not working in Xamarin.Mac

Tags: xamarin, sendkeys, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to send keystrokes to the active application using Visual Studio Mac. I followed this answer: [SendKeys for Xamarin.Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864506/sendkeys-for-xamarin-mac)

```
using (var eventSource = new CGEventSource(CGEventSourceStateID.HidSystem))
{
    var eventString = "1234";

    foreach (var eventChar in eventString)
    {
        ushort key;

        if (eventChar == ' ')
            key = (ushort)NSKey.Space;
        else
            key = (ushort)(NSKey)Enum.Parse(typeof(NSKey), eventChar.ToString().ToUpper());

        using (var keyEvent = new CGEvent(eventSource, key, true))
        {
            CGEvent.Post(keyEvent, CGEventTapLocation.HID);
        }
        using (var keyEvent = new CGEvent(eventSource, key, false))
        {
            CGEvent.Post(keyEvent, CGEventTapLocation.HID);
        }

    }
}
```

Basically there's no real magic following other samples in other languages, however the keystrokes are just ignored.

Is there anything additional to think of, like sandboxing or something else? I'm running my application in Debug mode.

I tried already sending the events from the main UI thread as well as from a background thread. However, the keystrokes are just ignored.

Comment: Not sure how to solve this. But I do know that applications that interact with the system in such ways need to be given permission in the accessibility section of MacOS settings.

Comment: Yes, that would make sense and I would expect it by the way. But no alert came up so far when I tried it the first time nor does anything pop up in the accessibility section of the Mac settings.